# How to find list of standard objects which has lookup(Account) field?

Tags: standard-objects

[image: Look(Account)field in contact obj]

Hi Folks!!!!
Hope you are doing great,

I want to know how to find list of standard objects ?
if possible,i want list of standard object which has lookup(Account) field???

Comment: I guess the question is how do you want to go about doing it? Are you a developer? Do you mind making an API request and parsing some JSON or XML? Do you want something output via Apex? What is your skill and comfort level? Bottom line is there is no easy way through the UI, but through describe functionality, you could get to it with relative ease if you didn't mind coding or reading a bunch of JSON.

Comment: You can do it via API or here is an ERD from Salesforce which gives you a look at all sales objects https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api.meta/api/sforce_api_erd_majors.htm

Comment: this might suffice - search for the field `accountId` in the SFDC Object Reference Guide.  SFDC is good about consistent field names (plus of course `parentId` on Account itself